# Error message when running hadoop wordcount example

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, text-mining, word-count

I used this command to run wordcound example in Hadoop.

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.5.jar wordcount inputWiki/Wiki_data_100MB outputWiki0301
```

and I got error message like below.

```
2018-03-01 18:54:14,845 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-03-01 18:54:16,107 INFO beanutils.FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector: Error when creating PropertyDescriptor for public final void org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)! Ignoring this property.*
```

I used that command ran similar file before and it worked well. Could anyone help me on this?

Update results below:

> pal-nat186-66-224:bin xujingjing$ hadoop jar
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.5.jar wordcount inputGurtenberg0302/gurtenberg.txt outputGurtenberg0302
>   2018-03-02 17:23:58,961 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable 2018-03-02 17:24:00,164 INFO
>   beanutils.FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector: Error when creating
>   PropertyDescriptor for public final void
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)!
>   Ignoring this property. 2018-03-02 17:24:00,226 INFO
>   impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
>   2018-03-02 17:24:00,396 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric
>   snapshot period at 10 second(s). 2018-03-02 17:24:00,397 INFO
>   impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started 2018-03-02
>   17:24:00,781 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area
>   file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/xujingjing1314852612/.staging/job_local1314852612_0001
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist:
>   hdfs://localhost:8020/user/xujingjing/inputGurtenberg0302/gurtenberg.txt
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:272)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:313)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:203)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1570)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1567)     at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1962)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1567)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1588)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
>   pal-nat186-66-224:bin xujingjing$

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: I mean I would appreciate if you could give me any information on how to resolve it

Comment: **Not** an error message. INFO and WARN can be ignored and do not not prevent applications from running. That first line has several results if you just search it

Comment: Also a [mcve] should be provided so we can reproduce your issues. How is Hadoop installed? What versions? What code are you using? Input files?  `mapreduce-examples-2.6.5.jar` probably shouldn't be ran within a Hadoop 3.0 installation

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I understand the first line, while I got different result after running the same command.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I installed Hadoop 3.0 on my macOS, and I am using basic command to run the word count example. I used mapreduce examples-2.6.5 because I ain’t find the corresponding word count embedded for version3.0. The input file is an 100 MB txt file I got by using Twitter API with Python

Comment: Can you show the full output of the command? The code will error if the output folder already exists

Comment: Please [edit] the question, don't put it below

Comment: @cricket_007yes I just edited the question.

Comment: @cricket_007 what I did is I used -put to upload my local txt file to hdfs file system as input, then I ran the mapreduce examples-2.6.5 and gave it a new folder as output.

Answer (score 0):

The error is this

> Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/user/xujingjing/inputGurtenberg0302/gurtenberg.txt

So use

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/xujingjing/inputGurtenberg0302/
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal \
   /path/to/gurtenberg.txt \
   /user/xujingjing/inputGurtenberg0302/
```

> I used that command ran similar file before

The line in your initial command uses a completely different file

Comment: I got an error message like this ERROR: mkdir is not COMMAND nor fully qualified CLASSNAME.

Comment: Right, fixed it

Comment: Dear cricket, could you check this link?https://stackoverflow.com/q/49343226/8824687