# Incorrect JAVA_HOME path when Installation of Approx-Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

I am trying to install `ApproxMapreduce` on `Hadoop 3.0.0` on my Mac. And I followed the instructions from this link that worked for `Hadoop 1.1.2`.
https://github.com/goiri/ApproxHadoop

And I got an error message saying:

```
Error: `JAVA_HOME` is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java/bin/java
```

While I set my `JAVA_HOME` path when I installed Hadoop. What should I change in order to get the `ApproxMapreduce` work? I've set the `JAVA_HOME` to my java home directory and it's not working.

Comment: `JavaAppletPlugin` is not where Java is installed... See https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/ Also, if wouldn't really recommend running that code with Hadoop 3 since it's not been updated in 3 years

Comment: @cricket_007 I am trying to run an ApproxHadoop K means application on my Hadoop3.0.0. And I can't find any related resources. Do you have any resources? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. I have not needed to run MapReduce code in years. Your error is not related to Hadoop anyway. Your JAVA_HOME variable is not configured correctly in `hadoop-env.sh`

Comment: @cricket_007 I've changed my hadoop-env.sh to what shown below:     
                                                                                                                  **# Extra Java runtime options for all Hadoop commands. We don't support
# IPv6 yet/still, so by default the preference is set to IPv4.
 export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
 export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home"**

Comment: And it's not working

Comment: Hadoop doesn't support Java 9. And if you are not using Kerberos, then lose the krb5 properties